# javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I am getting this error when i try to connect to hive metastore using Spark SQL HiveContext.

i am running this on standalone cluster using spark-submit command from my desktop, not from the hadoop cluster.

Is it something to do with Security related issue? do i have to add something in the hive_site.xml? is there anything we need to update in the below entry?

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>
```

The spark version is 1.4.0 and the hive-site.xml is placed under conf folder.

below is the error log.

```
15/08/25 18:27:15 INFO HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 0.13.1
15/08/25 18:27:16 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://metastore.com:9083
15/08/25 18:27:16 ERROR TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Ker
beros tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:167)
        at com.cap1.ct.SparkSQLHive.main(SparkSQLHive.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        ... 35 more
15/08/25 18:27:16 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
15/08/25 18:27:16 INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
15/08/25 18:27:17 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://metastore.com:9083
15/08/25 18:27:17 ERROR TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Ker
beros tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:167)
        at com.cap1.ct.SparkSQLHive.main(SparkSQLHive.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: Running a search on StackOverflow with keywords `hive Kerberos` yields 70 answers. Might be a good standing point to investigate. But believe me, Kerberos issues are **painful** (there's a presentation scheduled at the next Apache BigData convention named *"Kerberos and Hadoop, Madness beyond the Gate"*)

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite: your hive-site.xml works for hive cli with kerberos enabled.

Spark with hive needs another **property**:

`-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false`

Quote from [official troubleshooting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html)

```
GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos Ticket)
Cause: This may occur if no valid Kerberos credentials are obtained. In particular, this occurs if you want the underlying mechanism to obtain credentials but you forgot to indicate this by setting the javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly system property value to false (for example via -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false in your execution command).
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is inherently tied to krb5.config file which has permissible servers. If it's not found or doesn't have a server domain entry then you may run into this.